# Wicket - "doubled" UTF-8 encoding

Tags: encoding, build, wicket

I have a Wicket 1.4 app. My .html files are in UTF-8.

But when rendered, the page is doubly-encoded, like if the UTF-8 content was treated as cp1250 and converted to UTF8.

Maven's pom.xml:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
  <inherited>true</inherited>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
    <optimize>true</optimize>
    <debug>true</debug>
    <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any ideas what should I check?

***Update:***  I've found the answer, see below. However, can I set the default encoding which should be used when reading resources? Setting Within the application is preffered over env vars.

Thanks,
Ondra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.apache.wicket.settings.Settings` have a `setDefaultMarkupEncoding()` method, which should do what you want.

Comment: I'm amazed that this isn't the default, at least when reading from inside a jar file.

Comment: in Wicket 6+: getMarkupSettings().setDefaultMarkupEncoding("UTF-8");

Answer (score 1):

Wicket pays attention to the XML prolog. So what was missing was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

in the panel's .html file.

Comment: I think this is much more portable, especially when considering that pages/components can be embedded (treated as library) inside another app, and the parent app might have different settings. While `UTF-8` is certainly a best practice, there are cases while it's not practical to force the app to not use any other encoding.